# Using if/else on the same line with return statement

Tags: python, syntax, return, conditional-operator

I'm trying to condense my code by putting my conditional statement onto one line.

```
def get_middle(s):
    if len(s)%2 == 1: return(s[int(len(s)/2)]) 
    else: return(s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])
```

This works just fine. 
I tried to do it this way:

```
return(s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else return(s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])
```

but I'm met with a syntax error at the end of that line.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from solution import *
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 5
    return(s[int(len(s)/2)]) if (len(s)%2 == 1) else (return(s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)]))
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also:
This is mainly just because I'm curious. I understand in a real-world application this code would be too hard to interpret.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the actual error you get, please edit your question to include a copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output.

Comment: You can't have the `return` keyword inside an expression.  Why are you trying to fit this all on one line?  No one who looks at this code will be able to tell what it does.

Comment: Your "condensed" code is extremely hard to read. Why do you want it one-lined? Spread to multiple lines, it will look awesome.

Comment: By the way, the code you say "works just fine" shouldn't. At least not how you show it to us with invalid indentation. For most languages indentation is just nice to have for people reading the code, but in the case of Python it's actually significant for the code to compile without errors. When posting code here, please copy-paste it, don't rewrite it. Rewriting the code might lead to mistakes that can confuse us or think that's the real error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It runs just fine with that indentation, but I know what you mean.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude python only requires indentation if you bring the statement in a block to the next line. You can write multiple statements on the same line after a colon even, by separating them with semicolons. It is a common practice in code golfing.

Comment: @DillonDavis I'm thinking about the `def get_middle(s):` part. Yes one could write the whole function in one line, but in the code as show it isn't.

Comment: @KuboMD As I just told Dillon in my previous comment, with that function definition it *shouldn't* work as you show it. Perhaps your own code is properly indented, but it isn't in your question here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see now, you are correct- his `if` and `else` should have a whitespace character in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the `return` keyword called again, because you already have the return at the start of the if and the else.

Do this instead:

```
return(s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else (s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])
```

Also,

that line is super unclear, maybe you should have sticked to the regular if and else statement, as you probably won't undertant a thing after coming one month later.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like:

```
return(s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else (s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what benefit you perceive from reducing the line count like this. Much better would be to refactor the index calculation using the `divmod` function, then using a conditional expression to compute the return value.

```
def get_middle(s):
    middle, r = divmod(len(s), 2)
    return s[middle] + (s[middle - 1] if r == 0 else 0)
```

Whether you want to use the conditional expression in place of an ordinary `if` statement is a matter of opinion:

```
if r == 1:
    return s[middle]
else:
    return s[middle] + s[middle - 1]
```

Comment: `s[middle - 1] if r == 1 else 0` is the other way round. Should be `s[middle - 1] if r == 0 else 0`

Answer (score 1):

Return should have the if-else block *within* itself.

Here, the if-else block is `(s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])`. So, you should write:

```py
return((s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else (s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)])).
```

I tested this, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could use very long and rather unreadable lambda function:

```
get_middle = (lambda s: (s[int(len(s)/2)]) if len(s)%2 == 1 else (s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)]))
```

but, it is significantly better not to find target in shorten every function. Readability counts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 2nd return :

```
return s[int(len(s)/2)] if len(s)%2 == 1 else s[int(len(s)/2)-1] + s[int(len(s)/2)]
```

The inline if else is the same as the ternary operator you can find in other languages, and you can use it to affect a variable

Answer (score 0):

A method use slice & get the middle from two direction:

```
def get_middle(s):
    return s[(len(s) - 1)/2 : -((len(s) - 1)/2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a halfway readable solution, try:

```
def get_middle(s): return sum(s) if len(s) < 3 else get_middle(s[1:-1])
```

Otherwise, if you're code golfing or something, try the following:

```
get_middle=lambda s:2<len(s)and get_middle(s[1:-1])or sum(s)
```

Or

```
get_middle=lambda s:sum(s[len(s)-1>>1:][:2-len(s)%2])
```